# UITabBar item title repeated in the bottom left corner - visual bug

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have `UITabBarController` with tabBarItems set in (inherited) code. For some strange reason I can't figure out, the title of the first tabBarItem is repeated in gray in the bottom left corner of the tabbar. I believe I've even seen 2 titles overlapping there. Any idea about the root cause of this? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Is you screen name in dashboard tab is "Dashboard"?

Comment: Someone has to be doing something with UIKit views that they shouldn't be. I would look for methods that are overridden that usually aren't.

Comment: Specifically, is `layoutSubviews` overridden in a custom subclass of UITabBar?

Comment: Thanks, I figured out finally! The call to `setupTabBar()` where the icon title and selected/deselected images was made too early in create() function, i.e. during viewController initialization. I've moved it to viewDidLoad() and now the visual bug is gone. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out finally! The call to setupTabBar() where the icon title and selected/deselected images was made too early in create() function, i.e. during viewController initialization. I've moved it to viewDidLoad() and now the visual bug is gone. Thanks again!